# asyncio is working in windows but not in linux

Tags: python, linux, kivy, python-asyncio

I or rather chat gpt wrote an app which should allow me to send messages to a microbit. In Windows this app works just fine, but in Linux and on Android it doesnt.

Here is a detailed description written by the actual code editor (chat gpt):

I'm developing a GUI application using the Kivy framework that connects to a Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) device. The application allows the user to send messages to the device. I'm trying to incorporate asynchronous programming using the asyncio library to handle the BLE communication.

However, I've encountered a couple of issues related to asyncio and the event loop when using the asyncio.ensure_future or asyncio.get_event_loop().create_task functions within the Kivy environment.

First, I encountered a DeprecationWarning indicating that there is no current event loop when using asyncio.ensure_future in the on_press callback of a button. I tried resolving this by using Clock.schedule_once to schedule the execution of the coroutine, but the warning persisted.

Next, I attempted to use asyncio.get_event_loop().create_task to directly create a task within the event loop. However, I still received the DeprecationWarning stating that there is no current event loop.

That is the Code im using:

```
import asyncio
import bleak
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.logger import Logger
import logging

from itertools import count, takewhile
from typing import Iterator

logging.Logger.manager.root = Logger

device_mac_address = "CC:70:D7:AB:6E:64"
UART_SERVICE_UUID = "6E400001-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E"
UART_RX_CHAR_UUID = "6E400002-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E"
UART_TX_CHAR_UUID = "6E400003-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E"

def sliced(data: bytes, n: int) -> Iterator[bytes]:
    return takewhile(len, (data[i : i + n] for i in count(0, n)))

class ExampleApp(App):
    def build(self):
        layout = GridLayout(cols=1)
        self.text_input = TextInput(multiline=False)
        button = Button(text="Send Message")
        button.bind(on_press=lambda instance: asyncio.ensure_future(self.send_message_async(instance)))
        layout.add_widget(self.text_input)
        layout.add_widget(button)
        return layout

    async def send_message_async(self, instance):
        try:
            if not hasattr(self, 'client') or not self.client.is_connected:
                self.client = bleak.BleakClient(device_mac_address)
                await self.client.connect()

            uart_service = self.client.services.get_service(UART_SERVICE_UUID)
            tx_char = uart_service.get_characteristic(UART_TX_CHAR_UUID)
            message = self.text_input.text + "\n"
            message = message.encode()
            message = message.replace(b"\r\n", b"\n")
            if message.lower() == b"q\n":
                return
            for s in sliced(message, tx_char.max_write_without_response_size):
                await self.client.write_gatt_char(tx_char, s)

            print("Sent:", message.decode())
        except bleak.BleakError as e:
            print(f"Error: {e}")

    async def disconnect_client(self):
        if hasattr(self, 'client') and self.client.is_connected:
            await self.client.disconnect()

    def on_stop(self):
        asyncio.ensure_future(self.disconnect_client())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    app = ExampleApp()
    app.run()
```

I'm seeking guidance on how to properly integrate asyncio and the event loop within a Kivy application. Specifically, I would like to know how to resolve the DeprecationWarning and ensure the proper execution of the send_message_async coroutine when the button is pressed.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What is a newline on the microbit?

Answer (score 0):

You get the warning because there is indeed no running event loop. You didn't start any yet, normally this is done by calling asyncio.run.

To be able to use Kivy together with asyncio, you should start the app as an asynchronous app, see also: https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.app.html#asynchronous-app

You can start the event loop (and the Kivy app) like this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    Logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    app = ExampleApp()
    asyncio.run(app.async_run(async_lib='asyncio'))
```

You could also instead of using bleak directly, use kaspersmicrobit: https://kaspersmicrobit.readthedocs.io

Sending a string via the bluetooth uart service is then as simple as

```
from kaspersmicrobit import KaspersMicrobit

with KaspersMicrobit.find_one_microbit() as microbit:
    microbit.uart.send_string("Hello!!!\n")
```

Working example using kaspersmicrobit:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.logger import Logger
import logging
from kaspersmicrobit import KaspersMicrobit


logging.Logger.manager.root = Logger

device_mac_address = "CC:70:D7:AB:6E:64"

class ExampleApp(App):

    def __init__(self, microbit, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.microbit = microbit

    def build(self):
        layout = GridLayout(cols=1)
        self.text_input = TextInput(multiline=False)
        button = Button(text="Send Message")
        button.bind(on_press=lambda instance: self.send_message(instance))
        layout.add_widget(self.text_input)
        layout.add_widget(button)
        return layout

    def send_message(self, instance):
        try:
            message = self.text_input.text + "\n"
            message = message.encode()
            message = message.replace(b"\r\n", b"\n")
            if message.lower() == b"q\n":
                return

            self.microbit.uart.send(message)

            print("Sent:", message.decode())
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error: {e}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    
    # you can use find_one_microbit() if you created your project with "No pairing required"
    # this will scan for microbits and connects to the first found:
    # with KaspersMicrobit.find_one_microbit() as microbit:
    #
    # If instead you created the project for pairing (just works pairing) you need the bluetooth address like this:
    with KaspersMicrobit(device_mac_address) as microbit:
        app = ExampleApp(microbit)
        app.run()
```